# ionic 3 center align ion-content to look better on wider screens

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, grid, ionic3

i created my website using ionic 3. The overall it is awesome. however on wider screens the entire page is left aligned or i should say ion-content renders left aligned.

the ion content part looks like below. please advise how to render it center aligned.

```
<ion-content padding style="max-width:1440px;height:100%;background: url('assets/images/background.png') no-repeat center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%" >

 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**Ionic Grid system**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) for that.If you need to develop responsive apps for all the devices view ports then Grid is the best.

> The grid is a powerful mobile-first flexbox system for building custom
>   layouts. It is heavily influenced by Bootstrap's grid system.

If you need to center something you can do it as shown below.

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2>
          //your content here
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

`<ion-col col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2>` it means
that it will start using the entire column and when it moves to a `medium size` display the column will scale to use `8` out of the `12` spaces, with an `offset` of `2` spaces, meaning it will be like this: `2 - 8 - 2`, so basically the content will be `centered`.

Comment: well my entire template needs to be center aligned. the ion-content needs to render center aligned based on screen size. what u r talking about is anything inside the ion-content using the grid

Comment: Put your content inside the grid and aligned it as I mentioned above.